# Запустить docker-compose перед bootRun-ом

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, maven, docker-compose

Я запускаю свое приложение на **java** из **IntellijIDEA** и использую в качестве инструмента сборки **maven**

Есть ли аналог плагину **gradle** для запуска **compose** файла перед тем как стартует приложение? Вот ссылка https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin

Тоесть, нажимая на эту кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы сначала выполнилась команда `docker compose up` **(windows)**, все сервисы поднялись, а потом запустилось приложение

Answer (score 1):

Хеей, кому интересно

Есть плагин для мавена:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.dkanejs.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-compose-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compose.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <detachedMode>true</detachedMode>
                    <composeFile>${project.basedir}/docker-compose.yml</composeFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Ссылка - https://github.com/syncdk/docker-compose-maven-plugin

Его можно запустить перед стартом приложения в идее если ткнуть на `Run -> Edit configurations -> Before launch + Add -> docker-compose:up`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]